# Bimodal distribution from uniform distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

I have a problem where I would like to generate a bimodal distribution from a given uniform distribution between different ranges of say, for example, (-1.0, +1.0), (-0.18, +0.18), (-0.12, +0.12) and (-0.15, +0.15). The example distributions can be viewed [here](https://imgur.com/gallery/I50fNcJ).

So the problem is that you are sort of 'carving out' the bimodal distribution from the given uniform distribution. Again, I don't want to generate a standalone bimodal distribution! From a given uniform distribution, the bimodal distribution is to be 'carved out'.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks